# How does position get calculated when using float with left/right

Tags: html, css

In bootstrap grid example below, it is using col-sm with col-sm-push/pull.
The col-sm-push specified the left/right value (offset).

I am not quite clear how would it work.

The second floating element comes to the left side of first floating element.

How does browser determine its position when left/right is involved with float? Any reference point it out?

[Here is the example link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex9&stacked=h)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">.col-sm-4 .col-sm-push-8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">.col-sm-8 .col-sm-pull-4</div>
```

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
```

Comment: Good question! The way i understand floated elements is, that they have no height at all and that's the reason why you can do, what bootstrap does, as long as their width's don't interfere.

Comment: As I formatting the code, realized that the @media css isn't correct, do you want to update it again. For answer the question, `left` and `right` values only works with positioned elements other than `static`, you should include the necessary code in the question.

Comment: Could I assume when a element is floated, it is treated/marked as relative position? Only under this assumption, that the left/right could work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: W3schools is a very bad reference for documentation, try MDN (Mozilla Developers Network) or the official W3C website (w3.org) for the documentation.

W3 says the following about float (right):

> Similar to 'left', except the box is floated to the right, and content flows on the left side of the box, starting at the top.

So this means that if you float your first element to the right, the second element has room at the left side and will try and position itself there.

Comment: It is not float:right, it is float:left with right:33%